# How to select distinct rows in SQL based on certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get distinct values out of my table. This is my SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.RM_Name, E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name,
E.SM_Mobile,E.Zone              
from tbl_employee E where day(RM_DOB)=25 and month(RM_DOB)=6
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
RM_Name       | RM_Mobile   | ZSM_NAme      |ZSM_Mobile | SM_Name       | SM_Mobile     |Zone
--------------|-------------| --------------|-----------| --------------| --------------|----------------
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |BULUNDSHAHAR
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |GHAZIABAD 1
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |MEERUT
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |MORADABAD
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |MUZAFFARNAGAR
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |NOIDA
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |SAHARANPUR
```

Query is giving duplicate value for other columns except Zone as it is different here. Is there any way to get output like this:

```
RM_Name       | RM_Mobile   | ZSM_NAme      |ZSM_Mobile | SM_Name       | SM_Mobile     |Zone
--------------|-------------| --------------|-----------| --------------| --------------|----------------
JOHNSON KYOSA | 1234567895  | Daniel GUPTA  |1296541235 | KAPIL SHARMA  | 2589631472    |BULUNDSHAHAR
```

i.e. if all other rows value are same except Zone then display one row(top row).
I tried below query but it doesn't work.

```
select * from tbl_employee where RM_Name in (
    select RM_Name from tbl_employee WHERE day(RM_DOB)=25 and month(RM_DOB)=6
    group by RM_Name having count(*) > 1
)
```

Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: What determins that the value of `Zone` is `'BULUNDSHAHAR'` and not `'MEERUT'` (or any other value of `Zone`)? Alphabetical order?

Comment: Alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  E.RM_Name,E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name,E.SM_Mobile,MIN(E.Zone)
FROM
  tbl_employee  E
WHERE
  day(E.RM_DOB)=25 and month(E.RM_DOB)=6
GROUP BY
  E.RM_Name,E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name,E.SM_Mobile
```

Comment: I am getting error as The multi-part identifier "E.RM_Name" could not be bound. similarly on every other columns

Comment: I just removed the `E` alias from your table, by mistake.  Try now.

Comment: How does this select distinct rows, without the distinct keyword?

Comment: Thanks! SQL noob here, wasn't sure how this answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to be returning 1 row at a time then just use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DISTINCT  
       E.RM_Name,
       E.RM_Mobile,
       E.ZSM_NAme,
       E.ZSM_Mobile,
       E.SM_Name,
       E.SM_Mobile,
       E.Zone              
FROM tbl_employee E
WHERE day(RM_DOB)=25
  AND month(RM_DOB)=6;
```

If you're going to be doing this for multiple employees, perhaps...

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT E.RM_Name,
           E.RM_Mobile,
           E.ZSM_NAme,
           E.ZSM_Mobile,
           E.SM_Name,
           E.SM_Mobile,
           E.Zone,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.RM_Name, E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name, E.SM_Mobile
                              ORDER BY E.Zone ASC) AS RN
    FROM tbl_employee E
    WHERE day(RM_DOB)=25
      AND month(RM_DOB)=6)
SELECT *
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function

```
select * 
from (select *,
           row_number() over (partition by RM_Name, RM_Mobile, ZSM_NAme, ZSM_Mobile, SM_Name, SM_Mobile order by Zone) Seq 
     from bl_employee t
     where day(RM_DOB)=25 and month(RM_DOB)=6
     ) t
where Seq = 1;
```

Comment: Worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.RM_Name, E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name,
E.SM_Mobile,E.Zone              
from tbl_employee E where day(RM_DOB)=25 and month(RM_DOB)=6 
group by E.RM_Name, E.RM_Mobile,E.ZSM_NAme,E.ZSM_Mobile,E.SM_Name,
E.SM_Mobile,E.Zone
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made